# Java basic collision logic with shapes

Tags: java, lwjgl, collision, slick2d

I have an array which contains shapes (Rectangles) and then another shape which when it collides with a shape in the array I want it to not be able to pass, so the array of shapes is basically an array of walls that the shape can't pass through. Here is how I'm currently trying to do it (example of W key):

```
private boolean CanMove() { 
    for(Shape wall : mazeWalls) {
        if(character.intersects(wall)) 

            return true;

    }
    return false;
}

if (keyInput.isKeyDown(keyInput.KEY_W)) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= MoveSpeed; i++) {
            char_y--;
              if(CanMove()) {
                char_y++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The array of shapes is very small so I'm checking it all - Right now it will stop but it will be stuck in the wall and unable to backout/go in any other direction. It simply becomes lodged into the wall. If anybody has a better way at doing this I'm using Slick and LWJGL or a solution I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Your `CanMove` method is either wrongly named or else you return the wrong value, since if the character intersects with the wall you tell it to return true, which actually should be false. Last time I checked you can't move if you're facing a wall.

Answer (score 0):

the common way how to do this is to count the one step forward before its happens and then decide if you can move or you cant.

So you simulate your movement, count intersecting and if it would be true, you dont move with your character.